# css3 transition slide to left

Tags: html, css, transition

I am working on a html5 & css3 website and i am stuck with the sliding transition. 
[here u can view an example](http://clubpenguin25.com/html5/) currently when u click the right arrow it will slide to right, i am trying to make it slide to the bottom, also the return arrow should slide to the top. From what i see on the code in the "bg" class:

```
-moz-transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out;
transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out;
```

if i change it to bottom it creates a weird effect. i know i am missing something very easy, can someone help me pls.

Answer (score 1):

```
#test       {            
            -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
            }


#test:hover {
            top:100px;
            bottom:100px;
            }
```

Test adding that for the hover. how many pixels you want it to be moved.